How parity violation in weak interaction relate to electromagnetism?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_interaction

After the Wu experiment in 1956 discovered parity violation in the
weak interaction, a search began for a way to relate the weak and
electromagnetic interactions.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(physics)#Parity_violation

Although parity is conserved in electromagnetism and gravity, it is
violated in weak interactions, and perhaps, to some degree, in strong
interactions.


Is former quote just "correlation does not mean causation" event? Otherwise how discovery of parity violation led to idea that weak and electromagnetism are one force (as electromagnetism does not violate parity)?

Why electromagnetism does not violate parity if it and weak are one force and weak one violate?


